# Setup gitlab-runner to run automatically after git push?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When I git push I have to go to the server the gitlab-runner is configured on and enter in the terminal "sudo gitlab-runner run" or "gitlab-runner run". and then the pipeline would start. And I have to be in the runtime-platform all the time. This defeats the point of a pipeline.

It used to work so that when I git pushed, the pipeline would start automatically, I didn't have to enter the command at all. So is there a way to set that up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are the following two methods to achieve that.

1. `nohup gitlab-runner run &` will keep your runner running as a user process and uses a config file that defaults to `/home/<user>/.gitlab-runner/config.toml` (see `man nohup`)
2. `sudo systemctl start gitlab-runner` will start as a service, and uses a config file that defaults to  `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` (see `man systemctl`)

In both cases, you will be able to logout and the runner will stay active.

Comment: Thanks for that! The #2 was the one for me. I had to double check my working directory, it was not the good one, so it failed to start too, if someone ever encounter this.

Comment: If using #1 consider doing `nohup gitlab-runner run >/dev/null 2>&1 &` to avoid the logs (by default stored in `nohup.out`) filling up hard drive space.

Answer (score 0):

The gitlab [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/quick_start/) is pretty clear :

> GitLab offers a continuous integration service. For each commit or push to trigger your CI pipeline, you must:
>
> - Add a .gitlab-ci.yml file to your repository’s root directory.
> - Ensure your project is configured to use a Runner.

### .gitlab-ci.yml part

You need to [create](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/quick_start/#creating-a-simple-gitlab-ciyml-file) a file named `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the root directory of your repository. The script part depends of what you want to do in the job.

### Runner part

You need to [install](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/) and [configure](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#registering-a-specific-runner) the runner.

The most simple is to use [shared runner](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/README.html#registering-a-shared-runner)

Comment: It goes without saying that I already did that but my ci.yml file has this part:
`stages:
  - compose

docker-compose:
  stage: compose
` I usually have deploy `stages:                                                                                      
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
   
build-prod:
  stage: build`... Could that be an issue?

Comment: So you just need the runner part and ensure your project is configured to use this Runner.

Comment: shared runners are not always the best or easier solution. Especially if you're working on macos. We'll have to wait a little more before those shared runners become the norm (they'll probably come with a fee at some point)